# critical section prob while loop

Tags: c, operating-system, while-loop, critical-section

Okay, i was reading the critical section problem from galvin's sixth edition. Thing is, the algorithm used in the problem has a while loop as:

```
do
  {
   while(turn!=i);
   critical section
   turn=j;
    remainder section
}while(1);
```

Initially turn==0 and for i=0, process p0 runs its critical problem. The `while(turn!=i);` evaluates to `while(false)`  for this particular case.

Now my question is if the while loop evaluates to false how come the following critical section is evaluated. And here comes the stupid part, if for any reason the **while(turn!=i);** has a semicolon then the following statements have no effect of the while loop! So, whats the use of the while loop in here!? :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the while loop will either loop infinitly, either do nothing. The while loop with a semi-colomn specifies that it should try to loop, but with no instruction being executed in the while block. Writing `while (1);` is equivalent to `while (1) {}`

A common usage of this syntax is when you just want to iterate, let say, until the end of string, to futher work. You would write something like

```
char *work_on_end_of_string(char *str) {
  int i = 0;

  while (str[i++]); 
  // now str[i] is pointing on the end of the string
}
```

In your case, as you mentionned that your program was multithreaded, `turn` or `i` seems to need to be different before executing the critical section. The while statement enable to loop on testing this condition, until a thread modify one of those to satisfy it.

Comment: sorry but it ain't clear what u want to say! it doesn't answer my query, how does while loop execute if the condition inside is false.. it is equivalent to while(0)!

Comment: Does the example helps a little more ?

Comment: nah .. :| my question's while loop has a comparison inside it.. so, even if it evaluates to true why do i have a while loop ? it won't be executed in any case!!

Comment: Does your program uses multithreading ? Because if `turn` or `i` are atomically accessible, this while loop could be a solution to wait for them to change their value to something not satisfying the condition.

Comment: as a matter of fact it does use multi threading.. critical section is a problem of multi threading.. initially i==0, turn==i, now the while loop says while(turn!=0); if this while loop will never be executed whats the point of using it? keep in mind that another process is being executed concurrently which utilises the value of turn!!

Comment: Because if somehow `turn` and `i` take the same values, it will loop until another thread modify one of those, stopping the excecution of the current thread.

Comment: ahh.. i don't know what i was thinking .. it was such a small thing.. thanks a lot bud! :)

Answer (score 1):

if the condition in the while loop is false then the critical section of process P0 will execute and if the condition is true the while loop iterates (think it as the process P0 goes to sleep) until the value of turn has been changed by the other process which is currently running its critical section.